# Sticky notes on different desktops

Tags: windows, windows-10, sticky-notes

I want to add separate sticky notes to each desktop on Windows 10. But I cannot move a note separately to different desktop instead the widget moves with notes. How to overcome this. I want to separately move each note.

Comment: That would be good if someone could shed light on this as Notepad behaves exactly as @Abhishek wants Sticky Notes to do.